# Equal Height nested divs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

So I'm working on a group of content boxes that each contain an image, content and a border at the bottom of the container. Now I need to get the containers equal in height (as it looks a lot neater) but I'm having trouble as the `div` i am applying the border to is within the `col-xx-xx` `div`, as I want the guttering to apply.

edit: thought it was worth mentioning, that the `full-height-item` divs are all working and 100% height of their parent `.full-height`, however I cannot get the `div` within these to either fill out their parent, or sit at the bottom so I can apply a `border-bottom` or `background-color` and height of the `div` depending on which method would be best?

here is my markup:

```css
.full-height {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
}

.full-height-item {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul class="full-height">
    <li class="full-height-item col-md-4">
        <div>
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" src="url" /><br>
            <span style="font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: 500; color: #0067b1">CONTENT TITLE</span><br><br>
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            <div class="full-height-item-content" style="height: 1em; background-color: black"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="full-height-item col-md-4">
        <div>
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" src="url" /><br>
            <span style="font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: 500; color: #0067b1">CONTENT TITLE</span><br><br>
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            <div class="full-height-item-content" style="height: 1em; background-color: black"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="full-height-item col-md-4">
        <div>
            <img alt="" class="img-responsive center-block" src="url" /><br>
            <span style="font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: 500; color: #0067b1">CONTENT TITLE</span><br><br>
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            <div class="full-height-item-content" style="height: 1em; background-color: black"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is all that text supposed to be within the `.full-height-item-content` div?

Comment: hi, no. that is a div used to create the border at the bottom. I wasn't sure which was the best way to go about it, whether to make the container div full height of full-height-item and then apply a bottom border, or add full-height-item-content and align it to the bottom.

Looking back at this though, I can see in order for the latter to work it would require the full-height-item-content to be below the container div, not inside it.

Comment: Also, the text isn't wrapped in any element. This makes the text block an *anonymous element*, which makes it unselectable and therefore unstyleable (except it can inherit styles from the parent).

Comment: ye, I hadn't got that far yet, as I wanted to get the functionality working correctly first, before looking at the content itself. I've been using bootstrap for about a year now, and this has been the bane of my life for the last year (vertical aligning that is). I'm getting there though, starting to get a better grasp of everything!

Comment: basically the issue is trying to get the unclassified div to be the full height of the parent div (full-height-item) so I can apply a border to the bottom of the content, but have all the borders line up together. I can apply the border to the full-height-item div, as that is set to stretch to its parent div, but because i want the guttering between the content that is no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear to me, so I may be misinterpreting some aspects. However, here are a few issues you may want to address:

**1. Nesting Flexboxes**

When you create a flex container only the child elements become flex items. Descendants beyond the children do not become flex items and flex properties don't apply to them.

Your main container (`.full-height`) is a flex container, which means that its children (`.full-height-item`) are flex items. You've also applied `display: flex` to the flex item, which makes it a nested flex container, and the `div` child containing the content elements is a flex item.

However, the `div` itself is not a flex container, which means its child elements are not flex items and flex properties (like `align-items: stretch`) will have no effect on them.

So the first step is to make the `div` a flex container as well, like its parent. Flex properties can then apply to the children. Add this to your code:

```
.full-height-item > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

**2. Anonymous Flex Items**

You have content (the *text text text ...*) that is not wrapped in any element.
This is considered an [anonymous flex item](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#flex-items), which is able to inherit properties from the parent but – like [anonymous block and anonymous inline boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#box-gen) – is *unselectable* and therefore *unstyleable*.

So if you want to apply styles to the text consider wrapping it in a `<span>`, `<div>` or other element.

```
<span>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text</span>
```

**3. flex: 1**

You can tell all flex items to grow to fill the container, or you can tell just one. Here I'm specifying that the content section should grow:

```
.full-height-item > div > span:last-of-type {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    flex: 1;
}
```

With these adjustments you have three equal height containers with a border at the bottom.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/1s613h8g/4/

Comment: brilliant! this is exactly what I meant! My wording is probably just not the best! It was the nested flexbox that I was having trouble with! thank you sir :)

Comment: also am I correct in thinking this is the best way to apply the gutters in the new bootstrap? or is there a better way?

Comment: i've never used bootstrap, so i'm wouldn't be the best source of guidance for you there...

Comment: ok well thank you for all your help! it's saved me a few hours of frustration!

Comment: No problem Mark. Please consider an up vote and/or a checkmark if my answer was helpful to you.

Comment: hi michael, I tried but they're not public until my rep becomes higher?

Comment: also, ive been using this and have come across an issue with the width. Basically, if the content within the div (so in this case the text within the spans) isn't long enough to fill out the entire width, it's shrinking down the entire thing to the width of the content. does that make sense? if not i can supply photos!

Comment: Yeah, if you want to post details and links to images I'll be happy to take a look. But I'm at work right now. I'll be able to help you tonight. If you can reproduce the problem on jsfiddle.net that would be good, too.

Comment: Hi, apologies for the delay with this. here is the Jsfiddle (although the bootstrap isnt quite working), and you can see how they divs are only as wide as the content, instead of filling the designated section of the grid using the bootstrap class "col-md-4".  ive attempted to set the width of the div using the width and min-width elements but have had no luck, as I assume its the flex being applied to the divs that's preventing them from stretching out?  http://jsfiddle.net/nsq3op2e/

Comment: Just tell `.full-height-item` and its flex items to expand the full width of the container. You can apply `flex-grow: 1` to each: http://jsfiddle.net/nsq3op2e/1/